# Insert / Update MobilePush Demographics

Tags: marketing-cloud, mobilepush

I am currently trying to use MobliePush feature and GroupConnect as one of the communication channels. I know that when we initialize the MC SDK in mobile application it will send the contact data, device id, etc. to the MobilePush Demographics DE(The same goes to GroupConnect).

Here come my question. How can I change the contact id of those auto-generated Contact ID in MobilePush Demographics table. Let's say that my SFMC org use personcontactid as a subscriber key all along. Then when we want to send a push notification to the customers. We need to match the subscriber key(contact key) in the journey data to the contact id in MobilePush Demographics table so that the journey will know which device / application they will send a mobile push to.

Can I insert another MobilePush Demographics record with the same data except contact id(use personcontactid instead)?

Does anyone have a suggestion on how to accomplish this one ?

PS. Assuming that in the mobile application side they don't know the personcontact id of the customer. So the solution about setting contact id when the mc sdk is initialize in the mobile application is invalid.

Comment: Are you setting a `Contact Key` via the push SDKs?

Comment: Yes. I am planning to set contact key via the sdks. However those contact key is not necessary the personcontact id

Comment: My comment was geared toward understanding which of the two unfortunately similarly named things you wanted and to make sure you knew the difference.  Hahaha :)

Comment: You'd need to set the Contact Key through the SDK to that of the PersonContactId for Journey Builder to work correctly. Using some other value just leads to a completely different Marketing Cloud Contact being created that you'll be billed for and Journey Builder would not see the device as related to the Contact in your Journey. Somehow, the app's going to need to get hold of the PersonContactId.

Comment: @Macca Well yeah. If they can get a hold of the PersonContactId that would be nice. However if they can't get it then I need to present them with some other solutions.

Comment: Your contact is going to get created in the Marketing Cloud whether you set the contact key or not.  You might as well use the 1 tool, Contact Key, provided to identify customers across channels.  The contact ID is an unfortunate miss in the current API/implementation.

Answer (score 0):

If you need the `Contact ID` then you must make a REST call into contacts to get that value.